# puppetlabs/apt 2.0.1 errors when using with frequency => 'daily'

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I'm using puppet 3.7.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to use the puppet module puppetlabs/apt version 2.0.1:

My following code:

```
class { 'apt':
  update => {
    frequency => 'daily',
  }
}
```

returns `'A String is not comparable to a non String'. at /etc/puppet/modules/apt/manifests/update.pp:16:39` on every runs !

Using `frequency => 'always'` or using the default value 'first run' by removing the `update` dict fix the issue. Does anybody know how to use an update frequency with the apt module ?

(edit) It seems that this issue is related to the future parser: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-1767

Comment: I would first assume that your Puppet version is just too old to support this module.

Comment: I'm sorry. My puppet version was 3.7.4 and not 2.7.4 !

Comment: Ah. You might wish to raise this as a module bug with puppetlabs then.